# How to set focus by changed data in DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android

First, I am sorry that I am not good at English, 
but I will try to write as good as possible.

When selecting a date from DatePickerDialog and selecting a date again,

focus on Picker is not move to changed date when first selecting.

how can I do for this problem?

**AddProjectOrEvent.java**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Log.d("AddProjectOrEvent", "onClick() execute!");

    if (view == TV_ADDpe_EvDate_startDate) {
        showDatePickerDialog(AddProjectOrEvent.this, TV_EV_DATE_START_DATE, dateSetListener, year, month, day);
    }





private void showDatePickerDialog(Context context, int FLAG, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener, int year, int month, int day) {
    Log.d("AddProjectOrEvent", "showDatePickerDialog() execute!");

    Flag_What_DateSet = FLAG;
    new DatePickerDialog(context, dateSetListener, year, month, day).show();
}





DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
        Log.d("AddProjectOrEvent", "dateSetListener_onDateSet() execute!");

        if (Flag_What_DateSet == TV_EV_DATE_START_DATE) {
            setText(TV_EV_DATE_START_DATE, TV_ADDpe_EvDate_startDate, year, month, day);
        } 
    }
};
```

This is the code of the problem I am talking about.

It's too complex, so I reduced for show you.

Picker is already impliments by this code,

I don't know what to implement.

Comment: Please Show the code

Comment: Can you add some sample code to make the question a bit more clear. Any code you have been trying with will be good.

Comment: I edited post that added code with.

Comment: thanks about all answers! :)
It was a lot of help to me, the beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

This coding will set the Date Picker with the **current date** for the **first click** and **selected date** for **second click**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private EditText signup_bday;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        signup_bday=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_signup_birthday);

        signup_bday.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDatePickerDialog(signup_bday.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }

    private void showDatePickerDialog(String date) {
        if (date.contentEquals("")) {
            Calendar mcurrentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
            year=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        }else{
            String[] split = date.split("-");
            day = Integer.valueOf(split[0]);
            int montx = Integer.valueOf(split[1]);
            month = montx -1;
            year = Integer.valueOf(split[2]);
        }

        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int curyear, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                signup_bday.setText(new StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth).append("-").append(monthOfYear + 1).append("-").append(curyear));
            }
        };

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                dateSetListener, year, month, day);
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though my code is immature,
thanks a lot to sincere your advice.
I will try to like this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your code, but from what you wrote, it seems like you're trying to add a date picker to your project. Here, I will provide a DatePicker that you're going to call in your Activity.

Create a fragment named `DatePickerFrag` and paste the following code inside the framgent:

```
public class DatePickerFrag extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    AdapterViews.OnDateListener mCallback;
    OnDateChangeListener mCall;

    public interface OnDateListener{
        void onDate(int month, int year, int date);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context){
        super.onAttach(context);
        mCallback = (OnDateListener)context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedState){
        Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int month = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int day = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
        mCallback.onDate(month, year, day);
    }
}
```

Then, show the date picker when a button is clicked like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Log.d("AddProjectOrEvent", "onClick() execute!");

    if (view == TV_ADDpe_EvDate_startDate) {
            DatePickerFrag dialog = new DatePickerFrag();
            dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datepicker");
    }
```

Now get the date values by implementing the DatePickerFrag's interface in your activity.

For example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnDateChangeListener{

    @Override
    public void onDate(int month, int year, int day) {
        //Get the set month, year and day here in Integers

    }...}
```

That's all.

Comment: oh, sorry :)
in fact, I am a beginner both stackoverflow and android.
Please understand the immaturity.
thanks your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code from below code.It will work.

public class DateDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements 
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    return  dialog;
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());

}
```

}

Comment: I have been very helpful your code.
thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need have a global declarance for calendar.

```
Calendar calendar;
```

Secondly, instantiate it in onCreate() of Activity.

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Now for onClick of EditText you can have a code like this..

```
et_calendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int YEAR = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int MONTH=calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int DAY=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(DummyDialog.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                         calendar.set(year,month,dayOfMonth);
                         et_calendar.setText(""+dayOfMonth+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+year);
                    }
                },YEAR,MONTH,DAY);
            }
        });
```

For the very first time, your dialog opens with system date..when ever you clicked some date on it, that date will be assigned to global calendar instance..So, from the second time on wards which ever the date you selected will get focused.

Comment: oh, 
as you know, 

I understood way to solve this problem by virtue of many kind answers!

Thanks for your interest once more.